# A question regarding linear transformation to null space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^7$ is a linear transformation, and $\begin{bmatrix}3\\-2\\1\end{bmatrix} \in \mathrm{ker}(T)$.
    Show that there is a non-zero linear map $S : \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R^3}$ so that $T(S(\vec{x})) = \vec{0}$ for all $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Thank you very much in advance! I was a little confused about this question. As I know the aim is to find a linear map *S* with an output $\begin{bmatrix}3\\-2\\1\end{bmatrix}$. But I don't know how to find such specific *S* or any matrix that can transform any $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ to $\begin{bmatrix}3\\-2\\1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: How about the linear map that sends $e_1$ to the required vector and $e_2$ to any arbitrary vector? Then $T(S(e_1)) = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take
$$S=\pmatrix{3 & 0\\-2 & 0\\1& 0}$$